# Vertical alignment in multicols environment with figures

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, multicol

I have the following lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multicol,lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0,0,0}, breaklinks=true, pdftex=true, raiselinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}
\subsubsection{some title}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}
\item  \lipsum[11]
\item  \lipsum[11]
\end{enumerate}
\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=.9\textheight, keepaspectratio]{img.jpg}\captionof{figure}{some title}\label{some label}\end{center}
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that there is a lot of vertical space in-between the items. Is there a way to make the text always stick to the top of the column? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `\raggedcolumns` to your preamble. (`\raggedcolumns` and `\flushcolumns` are the `multicol` equivalents to `\raggedbottom` and `\flushbottom` which control the vertical alignment outside `multicols` environments.)